# registerDefaults not reflected in settings app

Tags: ios

There are a lot of answers surrounding the use of registering user defaults and I have looked hard and am still stumped by the behaviour I am seeing.

In my settings bundle I have one toggle switch which I give the identifier 'sharing' give it a default value of YES. I see this toggle switch in the settings app, but it doesn't default to On.  Even if I remove the app from the phone and install again.

In my didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method I have the following:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"sharing"];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];

[defaults synchronize];
```

If I test to see:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[defaults boolForKey:@"sharing"]);
```

The default is set, but it is not reflected in the settings app.

If I then go to the settings app and flip the switch to on and test the value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL enabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"sharing"];
```

This will still result in YES which I would expect.

And, then I flip it to off and test again:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL enabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"sharing"];
```

It will be NO as expected and the connection now works fine.

So, basically everything is working fine except that before the setting is changed, the default exist programatically but it not shown visually in the settings app.

Hopefully, someone can point out what I am missing!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem was that I had 'Value for ON' and 'Value for Off' set to type String instead of boolean in my settings.bundle (Root.plist).**

I didn't catch the error initially, because the app responded as expected and could interact with the settings app.  The only issue was that the initial 'visual' value for the settings app wasn't set properly. This behaviour makes sense when I think about it more.

This tutorial helped me find my error:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html

Comment: Analog to Matt, I had the Default Value set to type String instead of Boolean in my settings bundle. Same problem there.

Answer (score 2):

Using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: forKey:]` instead of `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:]` helped me to simplify casting.